# Scala, change variable value inside Future

Tags: scala, playframework

I have code below :

```
          val trxRequest: WSRequest = ws.url(route.transcationRoutes).withHeaders("Accept" -> "application/json")
          val futureResponse: Future[WSResponse] = trxRequest.post(Json.obj("trxtype" -> trxType, "trxvariable" -> trxVariable, "account" -> account.toJson))
          var responseStatus = 0 // I want to change this variable value
          futureResponse.map {
            response => {
              logkey = (LoginKeyUtils.getEncryptedKey(accountId))
              session.addSession(accountId -> logkey)

              responseStatus = response.status // I change it here

              println(responseStatus) // variable changed

              }

          }
          Ok(responseStatus +"") //But here back to 0 again
```

I want to change `responseStatus` value. It's value changed inside map {}, but back to 0 again when outside map. Is there something wrong? I'm newbie.

@Mikel, Thank you this is the solution,

```
          val trxRequest: WSRequest = ws.url(route.transcationRoutes).withHeaders("Accept" -> "application/json")
          val futureResponse: Future[WSResponse] = trxRequest.post(Json.obj("trxtype" -> trxType, "trxvariable" -> trxVariable, "account" -> account.toJson))
          var responseStatus = 0
          //Need to retrieve as future
          val futureResult: Future[Any] = futureResponse.map {
            response => {
              logkey = (LoginKeyUtils.getEncryptedKey(accountId))
              session.addSession(accountId -> logkey)
              responseStatus = response.status;
              println(responseStatus)

            }
          }
          // wait for the result
          Await.result(futureResult, 5000 millis)
          Ok(responseStatus)
```

Comment: We often use future composition/transformation for such async operations. If you use `Await` here note that will block the play main thread. If use a lot of `Await` you had to configure the main thread pool to have more threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The future is executed asynchronously, so there are a lot of chances that Ok(responseStatus +"") is executed before the variable has been modified.

If you want to be sure that the future has been executed you can add this before the last line

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration._    
Await.result(futureResponse, 5000 millis)
```

But in your case I guess what you need to do is retrieving the response as a Future

```
val trxRequest: WSRequest = ws.url(route.transcationRoutes).withHeaders("Accept" -> "application/json")
val futureResponse: Future[WSResponse] = trxRequest.post(Json.obj("trxtype" -> trxType, "trxvariable" -> trxVariable, "account" -> account.toJson))
var responseStatus = 0 // I want to change this variable value
futureResponse.map {
    response => {
        logkey = (LoginKeyUtils.getEncryptedKey(accountId))
        session.addSession(accountId -> logkey)

        responseStatus = response.status // I change it here

        println(responseStatus) // variable changed
        Ok(responseStatus +"")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the point is **The future is executed asynchronously**. And right I need to retrieve the response as a Future and Await the result for it. It's work. Thank you

Comment: You don't really need to use the await here, in the second snippet you can see the solution without Await

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid use Await here.

Could simplily be

```
Action.async {
  ...
  futureResponse.map { r =>
    Ok(r.status + "")
  }
}
```

`Action.async` takes an `Future[Result]` as the http response